# TypeScript watch in a docker container triggering incremental build when no files have changed

Tags: typescript, docker

I'm running into an issue where executing `tsc --watch` fires an incremental build when no files have changed. Roughly every 10 seconds or so. This only happens inside a docker container running the latest `node` image. If I run `tsc --watch` on the project outside of the docker container on the same source, incremental builds are triggered on file change only as expected.

I've tried modifying the watch behavior of `tsc` as specified [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html) but I get the same issue regardless.

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "jsx": "react",
      "paths": {
          "@root/*": ["./*"],
          "@api/*": ["./api/*"],
          "@indexer/*": ["./indexer/*"],
          "@converter/*": ["./converter/*"]
      },
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.tsx",
      "secret.ts",
      "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
```

The Dockerfile for the image in question:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
CMD yarn indexer:dev
```

Some sample output, such as it is:

```
[5:56:11 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[5:56:16 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:56:21 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:56:21 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:56:31 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:56:31 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:56:41 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:56:41 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:56:51 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:56:51 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:57:01 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:57:01 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:57:11 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:57:11 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:57:21 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:57:21 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[5:57:31 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[5:57:31 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this? I have the same issue

Comment: I didn't, no. I think I ended up moving away from `tsc`. Sorry!